# Div onclick dialog open not working for some reason

Tags: php, jquery, html

It looks like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZBJE.png)

I'm very new to JQuery, and I tried to contact others but they didn't know it either why it didn't worked.

I'm really stuck with this problem, and I hope someone on stackoverflow knows the issue. If it's necessary to add more code please send a comment and I will add it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Maasduinen</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="javascript" href="script.js">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

         <div id="dialog-1">

         TEST
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-2">

         Naam Bed & Breakfast
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-3">

         Testing
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-4">

         Naam Bed & Breakfast
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-5">

         Naam Bed & Breakfast
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-6">

         hoi
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-7">

         Testing
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-8">

         nog test
         </div>

         

             <div id="dialog-9">

         Naam Bed & Breakfast
         </div>

         

    

</div>

<div class="maasduin-container">
 <div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" /> 
    <label for="spoiler" >Appartementen</label>
    <div class="spoiler">
        
        <div class="products-1">
        <div onclick="$('#dialog-1').dialog('open')"></div>
         <div class="maasduin-foto"><img src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\huis.png">
                   </div>
         <div class="maasduin-naam">TEST</h3></div>
         <div class="maasduin-locatie">Straatnaam 12, 1234 AB Plaatsnaam</div>
         <div class="maasduin-email">info@langenaamvandebedandbreakfast.nl</div>
         <div class="maasduin-telefoon">T 0478 50 12 34 / M 06 12 34 56 78</div>
         <div class="maasduin-website">http://www.naambedandbreakfast.nl/</div>       
        </div>

      
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
        <div class="products-8">
        <div onclick="$('#dialog-8').dialog('open')"></div>
         <div class="maasduin-foto"><img src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\huis.png">
                     <div class="maasduin-actiefoto">
            <img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\maasduinpas.png">
           </div>
                   </div>
         <div class="maasduin-naam">nog test</h3></div>
         <div class="maasduin-locatie">Straatnaam 12, 1234 AB Plaatsnaam</div>
         <div class="maasduin-email">info@langenaamvandebedandbreakfast.nl</div>
         <div class="maasduin-telefoon"> T 0478 50 12 34 / M 06 12 34 56 78</div>
         <div class="maasduin-website">http://www.naambedandbreakfast.nl/</div>       
        </div>

      
            
        
      <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" /> 
   </div>
  </div>


   <div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler2" /> 
    <label for="spoiler2" >Bed and Breakfast</label>
    <div class="spoiler">
        
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
                    <div class="products">
         <div class="maasduin-foto"><img src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\huis.png">
                   </div>
         <div class="maasduin-naam">Naam Bed & Breakfast</h3></div>
         <div class="maasduin-locatie">Straatnaam 12, 1234 AB Plaatsnaam</div>
         <div class="maasduin-email">info@langenaamvandebedandbreakfast.nl</div>
         <div class="maasduin-telefoon"> T 0478 50 12 34 / M 06 12 34 56 78</div>
         <div class="maasduin-website">http://www.naambedandbreakfast.nl/</div>     
       </div>
      
        
      <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler2" />
  </div> 
  </div>

   <div class="row">  
   <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler3" /> 
    <label for="spoiler3" >Bungalow en Chalets</label>
    <div class="spoiler">
      
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
        
      <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" />
     </div> 
     </div>


     <div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler4" /> 
    <label for="spoiler4" >Camping</label>
    <div class="spoiler">
      
            
            
                    <div class="products">
         <div class="maasduin-foto"><img src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\huis.png">
                     <div class="maasduin-actiefoto">
            <img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\maasduinpas.png">
           </div>
                   </div>
         <div class="maasduin-naam">Naam Bed & Breakfast</h3></div>
         <div class="maasduin-locatie">Straatnaam 12, 1234 AB Plaatsnaam</div>
         <div class="maasduin-email">info@langenaamvandebedandbreakfast.nl</div>
         <div class="maasduin-telefoon"> T 0478 50 12 34 / M 06 12 34 56 78</div>
         <div class="maasduin-website">http://www.naambedandbreakfast.nl/</div>     
       </div>
      
            
            
            
            
            
        
      <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" />
     </div> 
     </div>


       <div class="row"> 
   <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler5" /> 
    <label for="spoiler5" >Groepsaccommodatie</label>
    <div class="spoiler">
      
            
            
            
                    <div class="products">
         <div class="maasduin-foto"><img src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\huis.png">
                   </div>
         <div class="maasduin-naam">Naam Bed & Breakfast</h3></div>
         <div class="maasduin-locatie">Straatnaam 12, 1234 AB Plaatsnaam</div>
         <div class="maasduin-email">info@langenaamvandebedandbreakfast.nl</div>
         <div class="maasduin-telefoon">T 0478 50 12 34 / M 06 12 34 56 78</div>
         <div class="maasduin-website">http://www.naambedandbreakfast.nl/</div>     
       </div>
      
            
            
            
            
        
      <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" />
     </div> 
     </div>

   <div class="row">    
   <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler6" /> 
    <label for="spoiler6" >Hotels</label>
    <div class="spoiler">
      
            
            
            
            
                    <div class="products">
         <div class="maasduin-foto"><img src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\huis.png">
                   </div>
         <div class="maasduin-naam">hoi</h3></div>
         <div class="maasduin-locatie">Straatnaam 12, 1234 AB Plaatsnaam</div>
         <div class="maasduin-email">info@langenaamvandebedandbreakfast.nl</div>
         <div class="maasduin-telefoon"> T 0478 50 12 34 / M 06 12 34 56 78</div>
         <div class="maasduin-website">http://www.naambedandbreakfast.nl/</div>     
       </div>
      
            
            
            
        
      <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" />
     </div> 
     </div>

      <div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler7" /> 
    <label for="spoiler7" >Kamperen bij de boer</label>
    <div class="spoiler">
      
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
        
      <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" />
     </div> 
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Div onclick

```
<div class="maasduin-container">
<div class="row">
  <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" /> 
  <label for="spoiler" >Appartementen</label>
  <div class="spoiler">
    <?php
                foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
                {
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinCategory'] == 
              'Appartementen'): ?>

                            <div class="products-<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinId'];?>">
                            <div onclick="$('div#<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinId'] ?>-dialog').dialog('open')"></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-foto"><img src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinImage']; ?>">
                                    <?php if ($hotel['MaasduinPas'] == '1'): 
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="maasduin-actiefoto">
                                            <img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="\Maasduinen-NW\image\<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinPasfoto']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="maasduin-naam"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?></h3></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-locatie"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinLocatie']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-email"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinEmail']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-telefoon"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinTelefoon']; ?></div>
                                <div class="maasduin-website"><?php echo $hotel['MaasduinWebsite']; ?></div>                
                            </div>

                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php
                }
                    ?>      
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="spoiler" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Dialog that needs to open:

```
           <?php foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
                {
                    ?>
                                <div id="<?php echo($hotel['MaasduinId']) ?>-dialog">

                                <?php echo $hotel['MaasduinNaam']; ?>

                                </div>



            <?php   } ?>
```

Comment: please provide a working fiddle.

Comment: @Huelfe hmm, my webiste is 70 % database is that also possible with fiddle?

Comment: Uhmmm... may I ask where the JavaScript part is? I only see PHP? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Of course you may not simulate PHP in a fiddle, but you could just provide the "parsed" PHP in a fiddle. The important thing here is JS.

Comment: @hallleron <div onclick="$('div#<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinId'] ?>-dialog').dialog('open')"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some stuff I suggest to try:

- Id's must start with a letter. So try "dialog-"
- Don't have duplicates
- make sure your console does not show errors at load or when clicking

If nothing works, hit CTRL+U and save the source somewhere so we can check it (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Update: after fixing html issues, initialize the dialog:

You need to "initialize" the dialog. So, add a class to each dialog div, like class="dialog", and then add this somewhere in your code:

`<script>
    var opt = {
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 550, height: 650, title: 'Details'
    };
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.dialog').dialog(opt);
    })
</script>`

or just call it using `$('div#dialog-XXXX').dialog(opt).dialog('open');`, just remember to have the "opt" variable defined.

basically this tells dialog HOW to open the actual dialog. You can customize it however you like

Comment: I've changed the ID to dialog- didn't worked. And there are 0 error's in the console.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the div with the wanted ID exists on the page? We can't see it in your printscreen. Save the entire executed source code (hit ctrl+u) into a jsfiddle.net and give us the link so we can see. Or just give us an URL if you have it public.

Comment: Exactly. I see you have errors in your HTML. For example, the div you want to click doesn't seem to have any content so the size is 0x0.

Comment: Hmm, yeah you're right.. but when I add it inside the Product- container like this: <div onclick="$('#dialog-<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinId']; ?>').dialog('open')" class="products-<?php echo $hotel['MaasduinId'];?>">  it has content inside it and it still isn't working check updated jsfiddle please.

Comment: Found issue. Will post to answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much !! You're the best! :)